# Is there still unpredictable behavior with glob() in perl?

Tags: perl, filesystems

I found this piece of wisdom in the PerlFaq quoted in a chat board from 2000.

> Is there a leak/bug in glob()?
>
> Due to the current implementation on some operating systems, when you
>   use the glob() function or its angle-bracket alias in a scalar
>   context, you may cause a leak and/or unpredictable behavior. It's best
>   therefore to use glob() only in list context.

I read that this problem was fixed in Perl 5.6 but later heard a report that it still occurs in 5.10.1

Has anyone had any experience of recent problems and where would be the best place to find the definitive answer regarding this?

[Later..] The latest PerlFAQ says:

> 5.18: Is there a leak/bug in glob()?
>
> (contributed by brian d foy)
>
> Starting with Perl 5.6.0, "glob" is implemented internally rather than
>   relying on an external resource. As such, memory issues with "glob"
>   aren't a problem in modern perls.

=====

Finally: The problem that was been reported was due to the misuse of glob by using it in a loop after it had already given all of the matched items. There was no problem with it.

Comment: Define 'latest PerlFAQ'?  It is not readily visible at the [PerlFAQ5](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html) on [perl.org](http://perl.org/).

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that a page that I found that FAQ on was the latest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use The Source Luke and the  Commit History

http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/history/HEAD:/ext/File-Glob

update: While that long obsolete perlfaq5 item was there in [5.14](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.14.2/perlfaq5.html#Is-there-a-leak/bug-in-glob%28%29?) it is gone in the [latest](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#Is-there-a-leak/bug-in-glob%28%29?)

Answer (score 1):

I've just tested on **Debian Wheezy** with Perl **5.14.2**.

### Scalar context - Fail miserably

```perl
sub test
{
    my $dir = shift;
    my $oldDir = cwd();

    chdir($dir) or die("Could not chdir() : $!");
    my $firstEntry = glob('*');
    print "$firstEntry\n";
    chdir($oldDir) or die("Could not chdir() : $!");    
}

# /tmp/test1 (contains file1 and file2)
test('/tmp/test1); # Display file1 which is expected

# /tmp/test2 (contains file3 and file4)
test('/tmp/test2'); # Display file2 which is not expected
```

### List context (Works as expected)

```perl
sub test
{
    my $dir = shift;
    my $oldDir = cwd();

    chdir($dir) or die("Could not chdir() : $!");
    (my $firstEntry) = glob('*');
    print "$firstEntry\n";
    chdir($oldDir) or die("Could not chdir() : $!");    
}

# /tmp/test1 (contains file1 and file2)
test('/tmp/test1); # Display file1 which is expected

# /tmp/test2 (contains file3 and file4)
test('/tmp/test2'); # Display file3 which is expected
```

To resume here, glob `buffer` is not flushed, even when we are out of caller scope.

With perl **5.22-1**, both cases work as expected (scalar context).

Comment: I'm getting file2 from the scalar test even in 5.25.1.

Comment: @choroba I'll test again ;) Thanks.